# jQuery - Illegal invocation ajax FormData

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I was following this example: [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax) but I got a `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`. I was wondering what went wrong. The following is the code I'm using:

```
  upload()
  {
    var dataimg = new FormData();
    dataimg.append('file', $("#file")[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: "src/php/upload.php",
        type: "post",
        cache : false,
        contentType : false,
        processType : false,
        data: dataimg,
        success: function(data) {
          //this.setState({data : JSON.parse(data)});
          console.log(data);
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Is upload supposed to be a function? In which case you need to write `function upload()`

Comment: @shadow this is react, I should probably include it so people don't get confused

Comment: is the `type` attribute case sensitive. It should be `POST` not `post`

Comment: @TeaCode no it shouldn't matter

Comment: @TeaCode definitely something to do with dataimg

Comment: same issue for me